# Crop PDF (A4->A5) automatically before printing

Tags: pdf, printing, automation

I'm repeatedly printing documents with the same layout. The documents are generated as 1 A4 page, but the real content when cropped fits easily on an A5 and can (and should) be even enlarged.

Right now I'm:

- printing the document as PDF
- cropping the documents manually in Acrobat
- printing the cropped document with the "Fit to printable area" scaling setting (= upscaling the content).

The margins to be cropped are always the same.

Is there a tool (a virtual printer?) enabling automation of the process?

Comment: did you ever find a virtual printer or other solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

There is a command line tool called `pdfcrop`, it will be installed in `/Library/TeX/texbin` when installing MacTeX ([link](https://tug.org/mactex/mactex-download.html)). I'm convinced there is better way of getting that tool instead of downloading/installing a 3.2 GByte software package (but because I'm using LaTeX, I've never cared to find out).

Excerpt from man page:

```
Syntax:   pdfcrop [options] <input[.pdf]> [output file]
Function: Margins are calculated and removed for each page in the file.
Examples:
  pdfcrop --margins 10 input.pdf output.pdf
  pdfcrop --margins '5 10 5 20' --clip input.pdf output.pdf
```

It might be suitable for your automation needs.

Comment: Thanks, @jvb. I was thinking more in the direction of virtual printers, so that the automation could be triggered already from the web browser without additional steps required. But maybe pdfcrop could be a part of the solution.